# Get string as a value in formatted output

Tags: string, pointers, rust, borrowing

I'm trying to pass the "Tuple lessons" on the [Rust by Example website](http://rustbyexample.com/), but I am stuck on the formatted output implementation. I have this code, which prints the passed matrix:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Matrix{
  data: Vec<Vec<f64>>   // [[...], [...],] 
}

impl fmt::Display for Matrix {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let output_data = self.data
            // [[1, 2], [2, 3]] -> ["1, 2", "2, 3"]
            .into_iter()
            .map(|row| {
                row.into_iter()
                    .map(|value| value.to_string())
                    .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                    .join(", ")
            })
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            // ["1, 2", "2, 3"] -> ["(1, 2)", "(2, 3)"]
            .into_iter()
            .map(|string_row| { format!("({})", string_row) })
            // ["(1, 2)", "(2, 3)"] -> "(1, 2),\n(2, 3)"
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join(",\n");
        write!(f, "{}", output_data)
    }
}
```

But the compiler prints the next message:

```
<anon>:21:40: 21:44 error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
<anon>:21         let output_data = self.data
                                    ^~~~
<anon>:21:40: 21:44 help: see the detailed explanation for E0507
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

I've tried to wrap `output_data`'s result into a `RefCell`, but the complier still prints this error. How can I fix this issue, so that the `write!` macro works correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `into_inter` takes the ownership of `data`, that is, is move out `data` from `self`, and that is not allowed (that is what the error says). To iterate in a vector without taking ownership, use `iter` method:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    let output_data = self.data
        // [[1, 2], [2, 3]] -> ["1, 2", "2, 3"]
        .iter()
        .map(|row| {
            row.into_iter()
                .map(|value| value.to_string())
                .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                .join(", ")
        })
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        // ["1, 2", "2, 3"] -> ["(1, 2)", "(2, 3)"]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|string_row| { format!("({})", string_row) })
        // ["(1, 2)", "(2, 3)"] -> "(1, 2),\n(2, 3)"
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join(",\n");
    write!(f, "{}", output_data)
}
```

Take a look at [Formatter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html). It has some methods to help write `fmt`. Here is a version that does not allocate intermediaries vectors and strings:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    let mut sep = "";
    for line in &self.data { // this is like: for line in self.data.iter()
        try!(f.write_str(sep));
        let mut d = f.debug_tuple("");
        for row in line {
            d.field(row);
        }
        try!(d.finish());
        sep = ",\n";
    }
    Ok(())
}
```